# HERE maps Android: where is the RouteManager class?

Tags: java, android, maps, classpath, here-api

trying to integrate a HERE map into my application. I have a trial key for now.

Cant seem to find RouteManager. Its not on the classpath:

[image]

The only thing I have found is a class named "RouteManagerImpl":

[image]

Here is RouteManager in the SDK documentation:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-starter/topics_api_nlp/com-here-android-mpa-routing-routemanager.html

Any ideas why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Premium Edition of the HERE SDK, this was renamed some time ago to CoreRouter. RouteManager is only the name in the StarterSDK.

You should use the Premium documentation instead: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics/routing.html

Comment: It seems like @breakline is using the starter-plan and you are referring to the premium-plan which eventually didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit late to answer your question, But this scenario caused because I try to replace Premium-SDK (AAR file) with Starter-SDK and then Gradle build started failing with error `Cannot find the package...` even if I can see the Decompiled version of `RouteManager` class from AS.

Anyway, Following steps worked for me:

1. Delete the `HERE-sdk.aar` from 'libs' folder.
2. Remove the `implementation(name:'HERE-sdk', ext:'aar')` dependency from app-level `build.gradle` file.
3. Clear your project.
4. Download the latest HERE SDK from developer console and copy it into the 'libs' folder.
5. Add the `implementation(name:'HERE-sdk', ext:'aar')` dependency after the `implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` (in case if you have any JAR added).
6. Clean & Rebuild the project.
7. That's it. You can now import `RouteManager` class in your app.